# Menu resizes onto line below instead of full width

Tags: css

On [my website](http://www.olympiahaacht.be) the menu looks fine when you just visit the homepage. As soon as you open one of the menus the selected menu turns to bold and the last menu item jumps to the line below.

I want the menu to be displayed on one line and not jump to the row below, but I can't seem to find the part that's scr*wing me over. Anyone have any suggestions or know what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
#access .current_page_item > a, #access .current_page_ancestor > a
{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**To**

```
#access .current_page_item > a, #access .current_page_ancestor > a
{
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

**or**

```
#access ul {
font-size: 13px;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 0 0 3em; /*set this to 3em or 3.6em*/
padding-left: 0;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**or**

```
#access a {
color: #eee;
display: block;
line-height: 3.333em;
padding: 0 1em;  /*set this to 1.2125em to 1em*/
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that's what changed it :D But I can't find why it's doing that (should have added that too perhaps)

Comment: When font-size increase or bold it also increase the space in parent  element adding the width.

Comment: indeed, just can't find the right section to edit it

Answer (score 3):

You can reserve space for bolded font through adding not visible `after` content. Here is JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2r4xby06/1 (demo is on hover)

CSS:

```
ul {
    font:normal 16px Arial;
}

li, a {
    display: inline - block;
    text - align: center;
}
a {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    text - decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a:hover {
    font-weight:bold;
}

a::after {
    display:block;
    content:attr(title);
    font-weight:bold;
    height:1px;
    color:transparent;
    overflow:hidden;
    visibility:hidden;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Ploegen">Ploegen</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="VOOR DE JONGSTEN">VOOR DE JONGSTEN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="KALENDER/STAND">KALENDER/STAND</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow looks nice, so is it the padding that does the trick or is it something else?

Comment: Invisible (for humans) bolded text in pseudoelement `::after`, when you remove `height:1px; color:transparent; overflow:hidden; visibility:hidden;` you will see that there is bolded text which reserved more space as bold. Of cource it has to have `title` attibute to knows what text is as content

Comment: ooh sweet! Bit too complicated for me at the moment!

Answer (score 1):

```
#access div {
  margin: 0px 8%;
}
```

This will solve the problem.

When one of the `<li>` is bold it overflows ( the width becomes bigger ) cause the margins parameters can't be met. So either remove bold or adjust the margins.

Comment: You mean this margin right, from the `nav id=access role=navigation`? `margin: 0 auto 6px`

Comment: Oh I'm sorry.

It's on .menu-menu-container. 
media="all"
#access div {
    margin: 0 9.5%;
}

Comment: I think I must be in the wrong part. My I do that change, it moves the menu to the right

Comment: Add this css 
.menu-menu-container {
    margin: 0 8%;
}

Does it fix the problem?

Comment: I tested it and it works fine. Did you try to add !important?